# Crystal Reports 7 runtime

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports, runtime

I use a program written in VB6 that uses crystal reports 7 for reporting. my machine crashed recently. I managed to copy the program files to a new system, but when I try to run the program, a file related to crystal reports is said to be missing. I was advised to install crystal reports 7 runtime but I don't have the setup. Does anybody know where i could get it from?

The program vendor is out of business, so try figure out the dilemma! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Which file(s) does it say is missing? You might have to contact SAP (who bought Business Objects, who bought Crystal Decisions, who were formerly Seagate Software, the makers of Crystal), and that could cost you. Some Crystal 7 files are downloadable from [here](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/downloads), but it's mostly samples.

On a further note, Crystal 7 is years out of support so 1) they might not be interested in any case, and 2) the files might not run/install correctly on a new system.

Answer (score 0):

I have a copy of the version 8 runtime which *might* work.  To my knowledge, not a whole lot changed between version 7 and 8.

If you still need it, leave me a comment and we can work something out.  I have a puny web server, and would rather not post a public link.